# how to write a directive in angular js for input string replace with comma between a number and alphabets

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, angularjs

Hi i need to write a angular js directive where it will divide the multiple car ids with comma(dynamically added) seperated. If i type in the input "CON123"a comma should added dynamically when trying to enter another car id where it starts with alphabet(convert to uppercase) and ends with number only.

Ex: CON123,DELT3210,TOYS89067....

Here i dont know the string count of car id (either alphabet count or number count). But need to add comma in between number and alphabet.

The directive im using right now

```
   directive('uppercased', function() {
 return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(input) {
            return input ? input.toUpperCase() : '';
        });
        element.css('text-transform','uppercase');
        var ar = scope.car.carId.split(',');

      }
    };
   });
```

html code as

```
        <input  name="carId" type="text" ng-model="car.carId" uppercased  />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand the problem you should need a directive like that:

```
(function() {
  angular
    .module('test', [])
    .directive('uppercased', uppercased);

  function uppercased() {
    return {
      link: function(s, e, a) {
        e.bind("keyup", function() {
          var val = e.val();
          var pnltmtChr = val.charAt(val.length-2);
          var lstChr = val.charAt(val.length-1);

          if(isNumber(pnltmtChr) && isCharacter(lstChr)){
            var position = val.length-1;
            var output = [val.slice(0, position), ',', val.slice(position)].join('');
            console.log(output);
            e.val(output);
          }

          function isNumber(val){
            var objRegExp  = /^[0-9]{1}$/;
            return objRegExp.test(val);
          }

          function isCharacter(val){
            var objRegExp  = /^[a-zA-Z]{1}$/;
            return objRegExp.test(val);
          }

        });
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

### How it works

It listen for ecery `keyup` event. Then reads current value in the input box and store in the `val` variable. Then check the last and penultimate character: if the last character is a letter and penultimate character is a number then add a comma between them and update input value.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nRsStNn6igYVx9X8GOyL?p=preview) is a plunker of a working example.

Comment: This is what i expected thanks Marianoc.And Stack Overflow

Comment: Your welcome. If you want you can accept the answer :)